# What is the difference between Material and MaterialApp in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am developing an app using Flutter. If I choose `MaterialApp` as the parent widget of my app, all `Text` widgets in my app are underlined yellow. On the other hand, if I just use `Material` as the parent widget, no yellow lines are shown under the `Text` widgets.

What is the difference between `Material` and `MaterialApp`?

Answer (score 32):

`MaterialApp` is a widget that introduces many interesting tools such as `Navigator` or `Theme` to help you develop your app.

`Material` is, on the other hand, a widget used to define a UI element respecting Material rules. It defines what elevation is, shape, and stuff. Then reused by many material widgets such as `Appbar` or `Card` or `FloatingButton`.

The yellow underlines you can find in `Text` is introduced by `MaterialApp` as a fallback `Theme`. It is here for debug purpose, to warn you that you need to use `Material` somewhere above your `Text`.

In short, use both. You should have a `MaterialApp` near the root of your app. And then use widgets that introduce a `Material` instance (Such a `Scaffold`, `Appbar`, `Dialog`, ...) when you want to use `Text` or `InkWell`.

Comment: The `Scaffold` is especially important. All screens of your app should be wrapped in a scaffold.

Comment: @boformer Why that claim?

Comment: @nbro Scaffold is not that important actually. It for sure helps, but non-material apps don't care about it. The main point is to have a Theme instance somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

`MaterialApp` : The MaterialApp configures the top-level Navigator to search for routes or to define Home.

`Material` : For child UI widgets rendering & effects.