# What is the difference between Non-Material apps and Material apps

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Not a clear explanation is given in flutter documentation, it will be difficult for you to understand if are new to Flutter.
https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/layout#non-material-apps and https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/layout#non-material-apps

What is the difference between Non-Material apps and Material apps, And What is the concept on which it is built. Going forward, How can I decide that "This part of my flutter code goes in Material App or in Non-material app"?

[What is the difference between Material and MaterialApp in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51061147/what-is-the-difference-between-material-and-materialapp-in-flutter) is the link I referred for Material and MaterialApp, says nothing on non-material concept.

Answer (score 3):

Material Apps are the ones which are using widgets from the material library, it is facilitating the process of building mobile apps which are material desigin-compliant by enabling you to include off-the-shelf widgets like `AppBar`. As a rule of thumb, if you happen to import `material.dart` library to use a certain widget, then you're building a material app. otherwise your app is non-material.You can find more use information in the [MaterialApp class](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/MaterialApp-class.html) official documentation.

Comment: Thanks, So we can write a code including material and non- material concepts, If we are calling any inbuilt widgets then we have to import material.dart otherwise we can use default features of non-material (without importing any file)...Did I get it correctly...

Comment: That's not exactly true. Apps are free to use both Material and Cupertino design for example (Switch is a widget that use both).

Comment: Of course! material library will make it much easier for you to build professionaly-looking apps without reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Just a quick update: this is the new link to access the official documentation on MaterialApp class. https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/MaterialApp-class.html

Answer (score 1):

The Flutter Framework is divided into two parts Material widget (i.e. android based design guideline which is used in some views in android) and Cupertino widget (i.e. ios based design guideline).

For detail flutter framework i have attached the image:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Material app includes Material design specific features.

This includes but is not limited to:

- Changing the route animation (MaterialRoute)
- Adding a Theme
- Including Material localization support

Comment: Thanks for the input, will dig deep into documentation!

Answer (score 0):

By default a non-Material app doesn’t include an AppBar, title, or background color. If you want these features in a non-Material app, you have to build them yourself.

[See Flutter Documentation](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/layout)