# What is the use of Material Widget?

Tags: flutter, dart

What is the use of Material widget in flutter? even though we can use the properties included in material inside a Material App. What is it's key use.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51061147/what-is-the-difference-between-material-and-materialapp-in-flutter

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The Material widget is responsible for:

- Clipping: If [clipBehavior](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Material/clipBehavior.html) is not [Clip.none](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Clip-class.html), Material clips
  its widget sub-tree to the shape specified by [shape](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Material/shape.html), [type](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Material/type.html),
  and [borderRadius](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Material/borderRadius.html). By default, [clipBehavior](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Material/clipBehavior.html) is
  [Clip.none](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Clip-class.html) for performance considerations.
- Elevation: Material elevates its widget sub-tree on the Z-axis by [elevation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Material/elevation.html) pixels, and draws the appropriate shadow.
- Ink effects: Material shows ink effects implemented by [InkFeatures](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/InkFeature-class.html) like [InkSplash](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/InkSplash-class.html) and [InkHighlight](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/InkHighlight-class.html) below its children.

For more information about **Material Widget** go through this [link](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Material-class.html).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, let's see what the Flutter docs say on [Material](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Material-class.html) Widget.

> A piece of material and
> Material is the central metaphor in Material Design.

And of course, there is a lot more detailed explanation after this. Nevertheless, if we just stick to the above line, we can at least get a decent understanding of the Material widget.
**Simply put, It creates a piece of Material i.e. any widget wrapped with Material implements the basic Material design visual layout structure.**

Consider the following example:
Here we are trying to use some widgets from [Cupertino library](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/cupertino/cupertino-library.html) for rendering UI that's specific to iOS devices.

```
Widget _buildiOS(BuildContext context) {
  return const CupertinoTheme(
   data: CupertinoThemeData(),
   child: CupertinoPageScaffold(
     navigationBar: CupertinoNavigationBar(
      middle: Text("Home"),
    ),
     child: Center(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Text("Home Page - 1"),
          SizedBox(height: 20),
          Material(child: Text("Home Page - 2")),
         ],
       )
     ),
   );
 }
```

The resulting UI is shown below:

[image]

For rendering UI that's specific to iOS devices we use Cupertino theme. However, the Cupertino library includes only some widgets that help in rendering UI that is specific to iOS devices but for rendering some basic UI elements such as Text(), it still needs Material library.

This is where the Material widget comes into the picture. By wrapping widgets with Material, **it implements the basic Material design visual layout structure. The role played by the Material is similar to that of the Scaffold**. We might end up using the Material widget a lot if we are developing apps using the Cupertino library and not so much in case of the material library.